# How to use a rails gem generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to implement this gem:
https://github.com/styx/timeline_fu

There aren't clear instructions or an issues section. I'm not sure where to run `script/generate timeline_fu` to make timeline_event.rb

Answer (score 0):

Turns out rails itself does the work.

`rails g timeline_fu`